# How to write captured input from a tkinter entry widget to a json file

Tags: python, json, tkinter

Thank you for your time. I reduced the structure of this problem to make it as simple to solve as possible. I am working in python with the GUI developer, tkinter. I want to capture the text input from an entry widget in tkinter and print/write it in a json file. What I have so far is this example, which capture the text from the entry widgets and prints the text in the shell terminal.

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
   e1.delete(0,END)
   e2.delete(0,END)

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

This code does exactly what I want to do, **except that the text is printed in the shell terminal instead of a separate json file.** To print the text in a json file, I have tried alternative function methods like:

```
def show_entry_fields():
   f = open('name.json', 'a', encoding = 'utf8')
   print("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
   e1.delete(0,END)
   e2.delete(0,END)
```

Here, I hoped that the function would open the json file 'name.json' and print the text in that file in the same way that the first example printed the text in the shell terminal. This was not successful.

And:

```
def show_entry_fields():
   f = open('name.json', 'a', encoding = 'utf8')
   f.write("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
   e1.delete(0,END)
   e2.delete(0,END)
```

Here, I hoped that the same goal would be accomplished, but again it was unsuccessful.

Ultimately, the goal is to print the text entered into the entry widget in the 'name.json' file. While I have been able to print the text from the entry widget in the terminal shell (see the first example), I have not been able to find a function to open a json file and print the text in that file. Thanks!

This is different than any other question because this question asks specifically how to export captured text to a json file. Previous questions deal specifically with capturing the text.

Comment: It looks like you may be confused on what `print` does. The method `print` will ONLY print to console. That is what it is for. It will not write data anywhere else ever. When you are doing `f.write()` this is specifically to write to a text file. For `json` files you need to do `json.dump` and you need to be using a data structure that is compatible with json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write json, the first step is to create a data structure that can be converted to json. Then, you can use the `json.dump` function to write the data to a file.

Example:

```
import json
...
data = {
    "first_name": e1.get(),
    "last_name": e2.get()
}
with open('name.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

When you execute that code, and enter "Foo" for the first name and "Bar" for the last name, the file will have this as its contents:

```
{
    "first_name": "Foo", 
    "last_name": "Bar"
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was way better! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

This code works! Using open("file name", "a") and then write, exports the input from the entry label to the file!

```
from tkinter import *

def show_entry_fields():
   f = open("name.json", "a")
   f.write("First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s" % (e1.get(), e2.get()))
   e1.delete(0,END)
   e2.delete(0,END)

master = Tk()
Label(master, text="First Name").grid(row=0)
Label(master, text="Last Name").grid(row=1)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)

e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)

e1.config(relief=SUNKEN)
e2.config(relief=SUNKEN)


Button(master, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

mainloop( )
```

Comment: this won't create valid json data.

Comment: Here you are just writing raw text to a file. This is not a json format.