# Treeview doesn't save changes after closing the window

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have a treeview that we can add to, modify, or delete items, like shown in this picture [Treeview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELe1Z.png)

The problem is after closing the window, the changes in my treeview are lost and it goes back to its first display.

The functions that I used are :

```
    #delete the treeview products
def delete_product():
 x = SecTree.selection()
 for record in x:
    SecTree.delete(record)

#create a new window to enter a new product
def add_product():
 global AddingProduct
 global entry
 AddingProduct = Tk()
 label=Label(AddingProduct,text='New Product')
 label.grid(row=0,column=1)
 entry = Entry(AddingProduct, text='add text')
 entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
 button=Button(AddingProduct,text='Ok',command=lambda:[add_record(),AddingProduct.destroy()])
 button.grid(row=2,column=1)

 #add the new value in the treeview of products
def add_record():
 SecTree.insert('', '0',text=str(entry.get()))
 entry.delete(0, END)

 # Save updated record of the treeview products
 def update_record():
   # Grab record number
    selected = SecTree.focus()
    # Save new data
    if change.get() != '':
        SecTree.item(selected, text=change.get())
    # Clear entry boxes
         change.delete(0, END)
```

these functions are then each one given to a button.

My question is how to save the changes done in a treeview even after closing the window?

Comment: Write to a file, the data from treeview, or save to database and write a inserting function.

Comment: As @CoolCloud proposed you could write it to JSON(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51949976/how-to-write-captured-input-from-a-tkinter-entry-widget-to-a-json-file)  or Database(https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-sqlite3-module-in-python-3)